# How to get filename of file control on file selection event using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, filenames

I need to fetch only file name right at the moment user selects any file from the dialog box (click on "Open" button after selecting file or just double click on the file itself).

Is there any event of the file control available that can be fired to fetch the file name once dialog box is closed

Comment: I don't think there is need to show any code. But simply i am talking about <input type="file" name="fileupload" id="fileupload" value=""> and i want to fetch file name once we select any file from the dialog box.

Comment: @neeraj Have you tried listening to the `change` & `propertychange` event of the file control ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>

<script>

function get_filename(obj) {

    var file = obj.value;
    alert(file);

}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<input type="file" name="file" value="" onchange="get_filename(this);" />

</body>
</html>
```

**Live example:**
http://simplestudio.rs/yard/filename/filename.html